Image not changing in Chrome Extension I'm building
I want all images in YouTube to change to a.jpeg.
JS code:
const imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (image of imgs) {
    image.src = "a.jpeg";
}

Manifest.json code:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "BwnnyRxbbit Everywhere",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Puts BwnnyRxbbit's pfp everywhere",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
        }
    ]
}


YouTube is a SPA, so you need to listen to navigation (example), but a efficient solution instead of a content script is declarativeNetRequest.
